# html canvas javascript fill and stroke methods

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on creating squares with HTML canvas and javascript. However, it is glitchy. I don't understand why. I have created two javascript objects, one for hollow blocks, one for filled blocks. I am iterating through both arrays to create the blocks at animate. However, I can only get one filled block at a time. I have not been able to have more than one at a time. However, I am successful creating hollow blocks. The code is the same, but it does not work the same. Why is that?

```
function hBlock(h,w,x,y){
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
this.create = function(){
    ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
    ctx.stroke();
    }
 }
function fBlock(h,w,x,y){
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
this.create = function(){
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
    }
 }

function newblock(){
if(f==1){fBlocks.push(new fBlock(h,w,x,y));}
else{hBlocks.push(new hBlock(h,w,x,y));}
console.log(hBlocks);
console.log(fBlocks);
animate();
}

function animate(){
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
if(hBlocks.length>1){hBlocks[hBlocks.length-1].create();}
if(fBlocks.length>1){fBlocks[fBlocks.length-1].create();}
}
```

Comment: [`beginPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath)... But you could just call `strokeRect` as well.

Comment: You called `clearRect` everytime. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect